# Is there a repo for php5-gd for debian 12?

Tags: debian, php, apt, php5, debian-bookworm

I am planning an upgrade of a debian 11.7 server to debian 12.

When asking for a full upgrade, Debian warns me about is to remove php5-gd

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libpng12-0 php5-gd
```

I really need this. Sometimes, in a situation like this, I accepted the removal of package and I resinstalled again later.

I am here to ask you if there is a way to

- understand what is causing removal of php5-gd
- reinstall php5-gd from some repo, but compatibile with Debian 12 bookworm

Comment: Php5 isn't maintained any longer. You might need to compile it from source.

Comment: I found a solution here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/750501/167205

Comment: I agree with the recommendation in that link - staying with PHP5 will become harder and harder with time.

Comment: I know. I strongly agree, but I am only an employ, I have no decisional weight. I am crying every time I touch a so-old-system, but ... I am not getting any result. If you want to cry with me, we still have some ubuntu 14. And this is completely unmaintainable